# APC UPS -> Windows SNMP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, ups, apc

We have an APC UPS. I want a Windows 2012 R2 server to shutdown on a power breakdown (and the remaining power lasts for e.g. 15 minutes). Therefore the UPS should send a message to all servers via SNMP. I think this should be possible. Is there an onboard way in W2012 Server to listen to these messages? I've already installed the SNMP service in Windows. I also tried the PowerChute software (Business edition) by APC but did not get any results. Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [apcupsd](http://www.apcupsd.org/) for Windows, or the Powerchute Network shutdown software (not the Business edition you have).

See this answer as well here for SNMP discussions, but it isn't a recommended option to try: [APC Smart-UPS: remote power shutoff?](https://serverfault.com/questions/174602/apc-smart-ups-remote-power-shutoff)

Comment: Hi! Great answer - thanks! I think the shutdown software should do its job! Unfortunately it seems that the UPS management card is frozen. Do you maybe know if there is a way to reboot the card without affecting the UPS? Otherwise we would have to power off all servers/routers/network switches/...

Comment: I haven't seen them in a few years, but I think they had a reset pinhole that could be done with a paper clip.  But again, been a few years...trying to remember.

Comment: Right, there is a little reset hole. I'm just concerned if a 'reset' wipes all settings or just 'reboots' the management card. I also don't know if the USP power is lost when resetting... All I found was rebooting the card with console commands but it is not available at all at the moment :/

Comment: The reset button resets the network management card, so you'll lose all of your settings if you do that. It's been several years since I've used an APC network management card, but IIRC you need to install the PowerChute Network Shutdown Configuration Utility on your servers and configure it to communicate with the APC unit. Likewise you need to configure the APC unit to manage the servers. You'll do that from the web interface of the management card. There isn't any way that I remember to use SNMP to tell the servers to shut down.

Comment: Hi! We've now performed a reset on the management card. The power wasn't interrupted and everything works fine again. The shutdown software was the hight hint. It works! ;-) Thanks again for your answer!